# Jasmine web services automation "getting started" doc

Tags: javascript, web-service, jasmine

I have been working on nightwatchjs from past 6 months, before that I was using Selenium-WebDriver to do browser automation.

I have syntactical knowledge of JS and I assume that Jasmine won't bother me much, if it is browser automation. But I never tested `web services` manually or automation.

I have to start automating web service for one of our clients, using Jasmine. Is their a getting started which can help me understanding and then automating web services? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Will those links below help?

[Jasmine Behavior-Driven JavsScript](http://jasmine.github.io/pages/getting_started.html)

[Jasmine Introduction](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html)

[Jasmine JaveScript testing Cheat Sheet](https://www.cheatography.com/citguy/cheat-sheets/jasmine-js-testing/)

[How do I Jasmine](https://evanhahn.com/how-do-i-jasmine/)

[Automate node test with Jasmine](https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/test-your-nodejs-with-jasmine)

[Getting started with JavaScript testing using Jasmine](http://www.ontestautomation.com/getting-started-with-javascript-testing-using-jasmine/)

I am not sure how much you know about web services testing, here is a quick starter in general: [webservice testing beginner guide](http://www.guru99.com/webservice-testing-beginner-guide.html)

Comment: Thanks for putting them together, but since I have very less time. I am looking something soecific, `how to test REST, SOAP using Jasmine`. I have found this link http://it-ebooks.info/search/?q=jasmine&type=title but don't know out these which one is Web services (API testing) related.